# H2 syntax error in SQL statement during Spock test

Tags: java, mysql, spring, h2, spock

This issue is only occuring when running my test cases. Running the application and query itself works as desired.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement
```

Here is the SQL query

```sql
SELECT
  C.idCampaign,
  SUM(DATEDIFF(IFNULL(CPM.actual_end, CURDATE()),CPM.actual_start)) AS daysPaused
FROM Campaign C
JOIN CampaignPauseManagement CPM
ON C.idCampaign = CPM.idCampaign
WHERE C.idCampaign IN (:campaignIds)
GROUP BY C.idCampaign;
```

I've tried changing the variable names, using different variations of COALESCE, case statements and haven't had any luck.

The error message shows a * mark here before the bracket for SUM

```sql
SELECT C.idCampaign, SUM(DATEDIFF(IFNULL(CPM.actual_end, CURDATE()),CPM.actual_start)[*]) AS daysPaused
```

Comment: [`DATEDIFF`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=DATEDIFF&search=DATEDIFF#datediff) expects three parameters.

Comment: Why did you remove the SQL statement and error message that were essential for others to understand your question?!? I reverted the edit. Please stop destroying your own questions, invalidating the meaning of existing answers and comments. This kind of dysfunctional information hiding helps nobody. On opposite, you should rather add information, e.g. your Spock test.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> DATEDIFF( datetimeField , aDateAndTime , bDateAndTime )
>
> Returns the number of crossed unit boundaries between two date/time values. This method returns a long. The datetimeField indicates the unit. Only TIMEZONE_HOUR, TIMEZONE_MINUTE, and TIMEZONE_SECOND fields use the time zone offset component. With all other fields if date/time values have time zone offset component it is ignored.
>
> Example:
>
> DATEDIFF(YEAR, T1.CREATED, T2.CREATED)

Note `DATEDIFF` takes 3 arguments, the first of which is the units specification.

Comment: Is this the case for Mysql as well?

Comment: You could look up the answer yourself, MySQL is well documented.  One very important skill for every developer is the ability to find information on your own.  Questions that can be answered by simply reading the documentation tend to get downvoted on Stack Overflow ("This question does not show any research effort...")

Comment: I asked because I did not see 3 arguments in the documentation, only 2.

Comment: Your test does not use MySQL but H2, and you happen to use an SQL function which differs between the two systems. You need to consider that in the test. Welcome to reality.